# Find $2$ to the power $p^2-1$ modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given a prime number $p>2$, find $2^{p^2-1}$ modulo $p$.

I know Fermat's and Euler's theorem but I can't apply them here.

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Hint: $p^2-1=(p-1)(p+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$a^{p^2-1}=\bigl(a^{p-1}\bigr)^{p+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use Euler's theorem: $\gcd(a,n)=1\implies a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod{n}$

---

$p\text{ is odd prime}\implies\gcd(2,p)=1\implies\color\red{2^{\phi(p)}}\equiv\color\red{1}\pmod{p}$

---

$p\text{ is prime}\implies\color\green{\phi(p)}=\color\green{p-1}$

---

$2^{p^2-1}=2^{(p-1)(p+1)}=(2^{\color\green{p-1}})^{p+1}=(2^{\color\green{\phi(p)}})^{p+1}$

---

$2^{p^2-1}\equiv(\color\red{2^{\phi(p)}})^{p+1}\equiv\color\red{1}^{p+1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$

Answer (score 0):

Using a mountain for a molehill:

The Galois group $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_p)$ is generated by $x \mapsto x^p$. In particular, taking $p^2$ powers fixes $2 \in \mathbb{F}_p$, hence taking $p^2 - 1$ powers gives $1$ since the multiplicative group is cyclic.

**Remark**. This generalizes nicely to finding the power $p^n - 1$, as does the method of writing $a^{p^2 - 1} = (a^{p-1})^{p+1}$.

Comment: Said more simply: cancel $\,2\,$ from $\ 2^{ P^{\large 2}}\!\! \equiv (\color{#c00}{2^P})^P\equiv \color{#c00}2^P\equiv 2\pmod{\! P},\: $ by little Fermat.

Comment: @BillDubuque That's right. I intended to be a bit absurd with this post, since there were so many answers already anyway.